# Excel sort 2 column with missing elements

Tags: excel, sorting, missing-data

I have a sheet with 4 columns and N rows. I would like to sort the columns leaving the empty fields when corresponding value is missing in the other columns. I need your help as I don't find a way to solve.

Maybe the example will help understand my question:

[image: Example]

Many thanks in advance

Fabrizio

Comment: **1.** Is VBA an option? **2.** Explain what happens in the example please, it is hard to understand. At least what happens with the "b". You will increase your chance of getting the answer. **3.** Explain better what you expect to be the result. E.g. *I want the letters (rows) to be aligned in both sets of columns, leaving empty cells for letters that are not present in the original set.*

Answer (score 1):

### Copy all letters, remove duplicates, INDEX MATCH

You can try this:

[image]